# Why is datatable sort wiping data from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have 2 tables in my view both using dataTables , first table works fine but second table when i try to sort data with headers is wiping data from table.

## Demo

[image: one]

This is how i defined dataTables for my both tables

> to get the idea i used screenshot

[image: two]

## Code

here is my second table code to define datatables

```
var table = $("#customerTable").DataTable();
```

any idea what is wrong?

> If you need more code just let me know i'll update the question.

## Update

Based on code i shared in jsFiddle (link in comments) if i move my second table definer to success function of my first table like:

```
              // rest of function then at the end having like...
                var otable = $("#customerTable").DataTable();
            }
        });

    });
    $("#data_table2 tbody tr:first-child").trigger("click");
});
```

[image: three]

It will allow me to sort my second table data **BUT** it replace my data with first data (confused? :) see GIF below)

[image: four]

To see Video version click [here](https://www.loom.com/share/df97928b5aef4b9cb634af2266c7d615)

Explanation:

as you see my first selected row has returned data in second table which has value of `nullewqrf2wrtf` but my second selected row the returned data has value of `null`

when i click sort on my second data it returns data of my previous selected row `nullewqrf2wrtf`

Comment: Can you share the code in the screenshot with a sample of your dataset... Like a jSon object we could use to make a snippet or a fiddle?

Comment: @Bilel ok i try to make something...

Comment: Ok ! Just to be sure. In the 2nd table, It looks like you are dynamically adding (non-dom) rows with javascript... This is better done with their Api row.add()  https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

Comment: check what i made https://jsfiddle.net/robertnicjoo/ercL8zbp/4/ let me know if anything is less there

Comment: PS: this is my original code for better investigation  so except table 1 that i used dummy data second table wont load anything :/

Comment: @Bilel got any idea?

Comment: Still inspecting the code ! #customerTable vs #table_customer and the missing part where you render those action buttons...

Comment: i figured out something as well, will update my question that might help you.

Comment: Plus the concatenation is broken at some part I think... skipping to line breaks...  I don't know if it's the same code layout you have. Did you tried detaching your view using only the second table to make thing easier to debug?

Comment: check my update please

Comment: no i didn't use my second table separately, because data in second table comes based on first table selected row.

Comment: Yes I just got it in the code and why you are triggering ... :) You had to mention the logic behind in your question.

Comment: sorry for that :)

Comment: Still weird ! If data is still undefined, you better undo the recent change.  I suggest you hardcode a modal container that you can update it's content with jQuery... That could be those divs getting mixed up with other data. That can be valid HTML but not sure if Datatables parser could handle it.

Comment: no nothing is undefined, if you mean that i mentioned `null` that's the value of description column is not actually null :), all data are returning absolutely fine. the only issue that exist is ability of sort/order in second table.  If you like i can give you temporary link so you can test it yourself?

Comment: I prefer a working fiddle with a dataset.. I'll see what I can do tomorrow (or today) it's 5:15 am here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solved

The solution **for me** was:

1. Moving my update function completely to my first table success
   function
2. Double check my other functions in that success function and get
   misspelled `var's`

***With fixing my var's misspelled id's** etc. now i can sort my data and **issue in my update part has fixed as well**.*

Hope it can help others as well.

Comment: This part took my attention and not easy to debug : https://ibb.co/XJYG5WM ! Glad you found it :)